# What does this error message mean and how do i solve the issue?

Tags: java

I started learning java very recently and am pretty confused with scanners and input in general. For this example, my output is exactly what it needs to be but I get an odd error message, what does this mean and what is my mistake?

**The code, sorry if it looks terribly unorganized but it's my first time with something this long.**

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = sc.next();
        String b = sc.next();
        String c = sc.next();
        String d = sc.next();
        String e = sc.next();
        String f = sc.next();
        String g = sc.next();
        String h = sc.next();
        String i = sc.next();
        String j = sc.next();
        String k = sc.next();
        String l = sc.next();
        String m = sc.next();
        String n = sc.next();
        String o = sc.next();
        String p = sc.next();

        System.out.println(h);
        System.out.println(g);
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(o);
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println(k);
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

**The error message:**

```
Failed test #1 of 3. Runtime error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

In the test #1 of 3, perhaps no elements are passed to your program in *that* point.

You should *check*, calling the `hasNext()` method before accessing the *next* element:

```
if (sc.hasNext()) {
    value = sc.next();
}
```

From the official Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--):

**Throws:**
NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

Answer (score 0):

This exception means, that there is no value to read for the `Scanner` from the input on invoking `sc.next()` method.

So, you are trying to read more items then input stream has.
`Scanner` has method `hasNext()` which returns `boolean` to indicate if there still something to read in the stream.

You can rewrite your example, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```

This code will read as many values as your input stream has and print them to the console.

Comment: I just started learning Java, so I haven't studied cycles at all. I'm struggling to understand any of the answers given so far. This problem is from hyperskill.org/learn/step/9261#comment

Comment: Oh, okay, so the errors that occur, mean that there are no values to read for Scanner. Subbase, you have a basket (System.in) with two apples and taking them one by one with Scanner :) So, on the first step `Scanner.next()` will return the first apple, on the second -> seconds apple, but when you will `Scanner.next()` again, it will through `NoSuchElementException `, meaning that there no more elements in the basket.

Comment: alternatively to cycles, you can add `if` statement before each `Scanner.next()` operation.